# Get a database value using mongoose and displaying in the same page (ExpressJS and MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, mongoose, handlebars.js

That is my first project in web development in general and I am using ExpressJS and MongoDB. I basically want to click a button in my view page and then get a specific data in the database (mongodb) to show the content just above the button element. That is what I have so far:

My Schema (I have a different schema for users, but that is the one that I want to get the data from).

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');

 // Redacao Schema
 var RedacaoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   testing1: {
     type: String
    }
   });

 var Redacao = module.exports = mongoose.model('Redacao', RedacaoSchema);
```

Here I want to click in a button, get a specific data from the database and show in the same page above the button. I am using handlebars as my view engine. My view:

```
<div id="target">
</div>

<input id="receberRedacao" type="button" value="User data">

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#receberRedacao').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/users/usuario/redacaoteste",
            type: "get",
        });
        console.log(texto1);
        $("<div id='redacao-usuario'>A redação do usuário está aqui. >>> {{texto1}} </div>").appendTo('#target');
    });
});
</script>
```

My router:

```
 var express = require('express');
 var router = express.Router();
 var Redacao = require('../models/redacao');

router.get('/usuario/redacaoteste', function(req, res) {
    var texto1 = Redacao.findOne({});
    console.log('>>>', texto1); //testing the variable I get something crazy
    res.render('usuario', {texto1});
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a callback as findOne is asynchronous:

```
router.get('/usuario/redacaoteste', function(req, res) {
    Redacao.findOne({}, function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            // Handle error here
        }
        console.log('>>>', doc);
        res.render('usuario', doc);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the answers for my problematic code. I'll post the answers here as they may help others.

Server side: 
1º I should have a promise to handle the errors when finding a variable in the database. 
2º Can't use res.render. It should be res.json to pass the variable, otherwise it will return the entire html code.

```
router.get('/usuario/receber', function(req, res) {
        Redacao
            .findOne({})
        .then(doc => {console.log(doc), res.json(doc)})
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          res.status(500).send({ message: err });
        });
});
```

Client side: I missed the success function in the Ajax request.

```
function successCallback(responseObj){
    console.log(responseObj);
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#receberRedacao').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: "/users/usuario/receber",
        type: "get",
        success: function(response){
                successCallback(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```